# How to display a value as a percentage?

Tags: c#

I'm building a quiz in C# which works and displays the results as a string, However I would like the result to be displayed as a % - how would I do this?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int score = 0;

    if (qn1.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        score++;
    if (qn2.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        score++;
    if (qn3.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        score++;
    if (qn4.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        score++;
    if (qn5.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        score++;

    literalScore.Text = score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Well, what did you try? Have you looked at any of the [numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)?

Comment: you should probably turn your 5 if's into an if/elseif/else statement, otherwise if the first one is true, you still have 4 other if statements to check which you know cant be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not sure i understood clearly what u asked.. but what i understand from ur question is if someone answer 3 questions good his percentage should be 60 % and that should be written in the result..

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
 {
 int score = 0;

 if (qn1.SelectedValue == "Yes")
    score++;
 if (qn2.SelectedValue == "Yes")
    score++;
 if (qn3.SelectedValue == "Yes")
    score++;
 if (qn4.SelectedValue == "Yes")
    score++;
 if (qn5.SelectedValue == "Yes")
    score++;

 literalScore.Text = (score*20).ToString() + " % ";
 }
```

You have to multiply with 20 if the questions are 5, what if questions are 10, than you have to multiply with 10

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide [`FormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d830955a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `ToString()` method. In your case `P` needs to be used for Percentage -

```
score = (double)score/(double)totalPossible;
literalScore.Text = score.ToString("P");
```

From the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString) -

> The percent ("P") format specifier multiplies a number by 100 and
>   converts it to a string that represents a percentage.